# Oracle12c - EXPDP hangs when using NFS share

Tags: oracle-12c, expdp

I have a problem with the export via EXPDP for Oracle12 databases.

When the export is local, no problem.
When I use an NFS share, the export starts, creates the log file, then nothing.

**VM where the database is located:**
Oracle Linux Server - 6.10

**Database version:**
Database Jan 2022 Release Update : 12.2.0.1.220118

**VM where the NFS share is located:**
CentOS 7

---

**Export NFS:**

```
/MY/PATH IP_DB_VM(rw,no_root_squash,sync)
```

**FSTAB:**

```
IP_NFS_VM:/MY/PATH /NFS_MOUNT_PATH nfs   rw,bg,hard,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,nfsvers=4,nointr,timeo=600,actimeo=0,tcp,nolock        0 0
```

I manage to mount the share, to write on it with the user oracle.
But when I run the expdp utility, it hangs.

My expdp command:

```
expdp MY_USER@MY_DB full=y directory=MY_NFS_SHARE_DIRECTORY dumpfile=expdp_MYDB.dmp logfile=expdp_MYDB.log
```

---

The export appears in *DEFINING* when I look at its state in the database, and I am then forced to kill the process (the *KILL_JOB* does not work)

If you have any idea what might be causing this behavior, and how to fix it!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make the NFS mount work by changing the mount option `nfsvers=4` to `vers=4`. I also deleted all jobs in *NOT RUNNING* and *DEFINING* state in case it could impact the other export/import jobs.

What remains unclear is that another NFS mount with the same configuration, and using the `vers=4` option, still does not work.. I'll edit this answer if I find the cause for this 2nd problem

**EDIT** → I updated nfs packages on the other NFS VM, and reboot it. The expdp works now.